# Is there a difference between gunzip -c and gunzip in terms of system utilization?

Tags: utilities, compression, gzip

Is there a difference between `zcat/gunzip -c` and `gunzip` apart from the obvious one that one outputs it to the terminal and the other decompresses it to a file? I'm looking from a  CPU utilization perspective. One of our clients mentioned that they would like to have a utility that can view the contents of zipped file without decompressing them. They also gave the example of `gzcat`, but I read up about `gzcat` and could not find definitive evidence that it is more efficient than `gunzip` . I could possibly see `gzcat` using lesser IO than `gunzip`. Are there any other improvements ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gunzip` and `gzcat` are both convenience aliases for `gzip -d` and `gzip -cd` respectively. In fact, if you look you will see that they are implemented as shell scripts that call `gzip` with the appropriate options. So there is zero difference in CPU utilization or other performance characteristics.

The I/O difference could potentially find would depend upon whether or not output is being written to a file. But that doesn't really depend on how `gzip` is called since, for example, all of the following commands write their output to a file:

```
gunzip file.gz
gzcat file.gz >file
gzip -cd file.gz >file
```

If you *don't* write output to a file but to a pipe instead, for example like this:

```
gzcat file.gz | less
gzip -cd file.gz | mail root
```

Then you might notice a difference, but it depends on a lot of things such as how big the file is, how often and for how long the pipeline stalls, the amount of buffer memory in your system, etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot Celada :) This would really help make my case with them.